# How to display sine squared more compactly

Tags: formatting

If I have:

```
\sin ^2(\theta )
```

My output is:

[image]

This output just have too much space between the power and the parenthesis. How could I change this?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it, but that [`nath` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/nath) solves this problem if you use `\left(`...`\right)`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I can reproduce your picture only if I add `\left` and `\right` in front of the parentheses.

So just don't use them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\sin^{2}\theta$

$\sin^{2}(\theta)$

$\sin^{2}\left(\theta\right)$
\end{document}
```

By the way, without parentheses it's even better.

[image]

Comment: That raises the question, what to do if `\left`... `\right` is needed for a complicated argument? If we are lucky, it is a fraction and again paraentheses can be dropped.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen `\left` and `\right` are not *needed*: in cases like this, `\biggl` and `\biggr` (or `\Bigl` and `\Bigr`) are better. With the `mleftright` package and its `\mleft` and `\mright` commands, the additional space is suppressed.

Answer (score 0):

`\sin{^2\theta}` is another option.

Comment: wait... then you just get a space between sin and the power. I think you shouldn't do that.

Comment: @JouleV No, not at all.

Comment: @egreg I think it's like this: `\sin{^2\theta}` = `\sin^2\theta` (`\sin` doesn't take any arguments) = `\sin^{2}\theta`, which is exactly your first option. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @JouleV Since `\sin` doesn't take an argument, the braces are not removed, so the superscript is to an empty atom rather than to `\sin`.